# Extract information from a string using REGEX?

Tags: javascript, java, regex, maven

I have:

```
var str = 'WEB-3545 Detta är ett REGEX test WEB-3545';
```

I want:

```
['WEB', '3545'];
```

Tried something like:

```
str.match(/^(WEB-|DR-)\d+\s/)
```

The pattern I'm matching against is:
String should start with: WEB- OR DR-
Then follow with 1 or more numbers
End with a space

Ex;

So, in the example above only the highlighted part should match:
'**WEB-3545** Detta är ett REGEX test WEB-3545'

I can only run regex operations, not creating a loop or anything - because this is used in a Maven POM-file.

Both Java and JavaScript solutions are fine.

Thanks!

/J

Comment: Try `str.match(/WEB\-\d+/)[0].split('-');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex `^\s*(WEB|DR)-(\d+)\b` and use **[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** to remove the string match, since only need is capturing group

```js
var str = 'WEB-3545 Detta är ett REGEX test WEB-3545';
var res = str.match(/^\s*(WEB|DR)-(\d+)\b/).splice(1);

document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @jBoive : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be `/^(WEB|DR)-(\d+)\b/`, `\b` matches the word edge, no need to use `\s`:)

```
var reg = /^(WEB|DR)-(\d+)\b/;
var str = 'WEB-3545 Detta är ett REGEX test WEB-3545';
console.log(str.match(reg).slice(1));//remove input match
```